# Is it possible to set Messages property for KendoDatePicker?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I set DateInput property for KendoDatePicker.
Then, is it possible to set Messages property for KendoDatePicker?
I want to change placeholder text, "year","month" and "day", like KendoDateInput compornent([api is here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dateinput#configuration-messages)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could obtain that behavior by declaring both kendoDatePicker and kendoDateInput within your element.

```
<input id="datepicker" />

$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({

});

$("#datepicker").kendoDateInput({
    messages: {
        "year": "y",
        "month": "m",
        "day": "d",
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't have to redefine a new kendoDateInput, you must use the one embedded inside the kendoDatePicker you previously create and apply setOptions on it with your new messages.  (see solution below...)

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible, kendo DatePicker accepts only a Date object. You could overlay the input with your own element and put text on that.

Changing the input will cause your date from the date picker to change as well unfortunately. Therefore overlaying an element on top seems like the best solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  You need to reconfigure the internal kendoDateInput that is embedded inside the kendoDatePicker.

First, declare your datePicker with {dateInput: true} option.
Then, apply a setOption on the internal dateInput, as:

```
var dt1 = $("input1").kendoDatePicker({
        format: "yyyy-MM-dd",
        dateInput: true
    }).data("kendoDatePicker");

dt1._dateInput.setOptions({
  messages:{
    "year": "yyyy",
    "month": "mm",
    "day": "dd"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

datePicker._dateInput.setOptions({
messages:{
"year": "yyyy",
"month": "MM",
"day": "dd"
}
});

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).